# Mask grid on rounded corners

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create some procedurally created filter with a customizable mesh grid inside the frame. Geometry nodes are used for this purpose.

I'm still working on it, but I have no idea how hide overlapping parts at the rounded corners. Any suggestions on how I could hide/mask them?

---

[image]

---

Im not much get it how to use that raycast in my project.
In shortly, my geonode darwing every string from boundry box edge.
I controlling size and shape this filter by changing position of cube box faces.

Me using blender from short time not anything is obvious for me yet.
For now me will use some non-procedural way to hide edges by using boolean modifier.

---

Attaching my blend file
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/nw0154X7#link

Comment: without being able to read your node tree...pls upload your blend so we can read your node tree and don't have to rebuild everything, thx

Comment: Crantisz already gave me a good tip with "raycast". Me can update later working *.blend when me finish implementing that to my project.

For now curves that are "out" of frame. They are just dissapearing but now me know where to start ;) me should figured out this soon.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ray cast to cast a ray from each instance position to check if it hits the filled curve or not:

[image]